# Sort the data in the given way

Tags: sorting

Consider the data

```
data = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3},{x4,y4,z4},{x5,y5,z5},{x6,y6,z6},...}
```

with N rows.

It can be divided into N/3 sets of 3 rows. I would like to sort the data in a way such that the rows inside the each set will be aligned according to the growth of y parameter. Finally, if yi = yj, then the upper row must be the one for which xi > xj.

For example, if y2 > y1 > y3 and y6 > y5 = y4, and x4 > x5, then it must be

```
datasorted = {{x2,y2,z2},{x1,y1,z1},{x3,y3,z3},{x6,y6,z6},{x4,y4,z4},{x5,y5,z5},...}
```

Could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: `SortBy[#, {-#[[2]] &, -#[[1]] &}] & /@ Partition[data, n/3]`?

Comment: @kglr I think you meant `Partition[data, 3]`? But OP has added an additional requirement now.

Comment: @kglr : thank you! However, because of my stupidness I forgot to include additional requirement to my question before you commented...

Comment: `ReverseSort[data[[All, {2, 1, 3}]]][[All, {2, 1, 3}]]`?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, right.; thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map `SortBy[#, {-#[[2]] &, -#[[1]] &}] &` on your partitioned data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[5, {15, 3}];
partitioned = Partition[data, 3];
MatrixForm[MatrixForm /@ partitioned, TableDirections -> Row]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  4 & 2 & 4 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 2 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 3 & 5 \\
>  2 & 0 & 3 \\
>  4 & 4 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  3 & 3 & 4 \\
>  1 & 4 & 2 \\
>  1 & 1 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  5 & 4 & 5 \\
>  0 & 3 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  3 & 1 & 1 \\
>  3 & 2 & 5 \\
>  1 & 1 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
MatrixForm[MatrixForm /@ (SortBy[#, {-#[[2]] &, -#[[1]] &}] & /@ partitioned), 
 TableDirections -> Row]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  4 & 2 & 4 \\
>  0 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  4 & 4 & 1 \\
>  0 & 3 & 5 \\
>  2 & 0 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 4 & 2 \\
>  3 & 3 & 4 \\
>  1 & 1 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  5 & 4 & 5 \\
>  0 & 3 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  3 & 2 & 5 \\
>  3 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$